# Moving CodeIgniter install to a subdomain causes a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

On my new subdomain the homepage works fine, but everything else throws a 500 Internal Server Error. I'm sure its an `.htaccess` issue. I have a CodeIgniter-based web app up at GiftFlow.org and working fine.

web root `/var/www/vhosts/giftflow.org/httpdocs`

From my hosting control panel, I created a subdomain favorece.giftflow.org and cloned everything into it.

web root `/var/www/vhosts/favorece.giftflow.org/httpdocs`

When I call `favorece.giftflow.org` from my browser, the index page comes up fine, CSS included, but when I try to navigate to any other page I get a 500 Internal Server Error. My Apache error log says:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Here is my base_url in CodeIgniter's application/config/config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '').'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace('//','/',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/');
```

And my `.htaccess` file, in the webroot of `favorece.giftflow` is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|user_guide|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /giftflow/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 8):

You're redirecting to `/giftflow/index.php` continually. RewriteBase might help, as well as additional flags for RewriteRule. Try:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Additionally, CI usually auto-detects the `base_url`, so you're most likely safe with leaving it blank. The logic you're defining in your `config.php` is probably best placed in the main index.php file as well.

Comment: My pleasure! Good luck with giftflow.

Comment: @dolokhov: If this answer was helpful, consider voting it up. If it solved your problem, consider marking it as "accepted".

Comment: dolokhov: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work. @Colin: Just a reminder: vote up is a privilege that requires 15 reputation, dolokhov cannot vote up yet.

Comment: Adding 'RewriteBase /' to my subdomain root .htaccess did it for me!

Answer (score 2):

yes its works...!

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I try in http://mango.penguintechno.com